# How to count the number of elements within a vector as they pass within a tolerance band

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a vector of data that is cycling in and out of a tolerance band.  I need to start a counter as it enters and stop it as it exits, then input the duration into a new vector, and continue this process until the end of the data vector.  I am at a complete loss on how to approach this.  Please help.  I've tried loops and I keep getting the total count of the elements within the band.  I need the count of each cycle- not the total number of elements within the band.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to count the elapsed time between when it enters and exits this tolerance band ? Add the code which you have tried also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that I think will do what you are looking for. This code generates a random vector between 0 and 1 and sets an in_band region of >=0.5. The durations are stored in count_vector. This can be modified to fit your application.

```
vec = rand(100,1);

%in_band >= thresh
thresh = 0.5;
count = 0;

count_vector = [];

for ii=1:length(vec)
    %if vector enters into the in band region, begin counting
    if vec(ii) >= thresh;
        count = count + 1;

    %if vector falls back out of band, log count and reset counter
    elseif (vec(ii) < thresh) && (count > 0)

        count_vector(length(count_vector) + 1) = count;        
        count = 0;
    end


end

figure; plot(vec)
hold on
line([0 length(vec)], [thresh thresh], 'Color', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want (it's hard to tell from your question):

```
data = [8 3 2 3 2 2 6 4 4 6 1 4 6 1 1 8]; %// data vector
tol_lower = 3; %// upper limit of tolerance band
tol_upper = 7; %// lower limit of tolerance band

ind = (data>=tol_lower)&(data<=tol_upper); %// 1 if within band, 0 otherwise
d = diff([0 ind 0]); %// positive if data enters band, negative if it leaves band
result = find(d<0)-find(d>0); %// duration of within-band periods
```

With the example data, the result is

```
result =
     1     1     4     2
```